# Need help on a SQL select query in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm sure this question is fairly simple, but I am not very savvy when it comes to SQL queries. Here is an example table:

```
|Name  |N|
 --------
|Mike  |1|
|John  |2|
|Dave  |3|
|Jane  |1|
|Kyle  |2|
|Susan |4|
|Tim   |5|
|Joe   |5|
|Tina  |7|
|Carly |1|
```

I need to select all 'N' from this table that occurs only once. The result for this table should be 3, 4, and 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `having` clause for that:

```
select  n
from    YourTable
group by
        n
having  count(*) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. Never used the HAVING keyword before. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT distinct(N) FROM table_name;

Or am I missing the point?

Comment: I need to select the numbers from the N column that occur only once in the table. SELECT DISTINCT selects all of the numbers period, but only selects them once.

Comment: Ahh I see i was having a mad moment! Apologies ;-)